# Cannot sync/save android studio project permission denied

Tags: permissions, android, android-studio

I am a newbie in linux world and using ubuntu 19.04 and Android Studio 3.4.1
If I run android studio from terminal using ./studio.sh as root user, I cannot sign in to google account as it tells me to sign in through opened browser window and browser never opens,

if I run android studio normally, I am able to sign in to my google account normally but android gradle sync fails and says:

```
ERROR: /home/faizan/projects/SLA/.gradle/5.1.1/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock (Permission denied)
```

And also I am unable to save any changes.